# xml data automatically scrolls across screen in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, uiscrollview, uilabel

There are two parts to this that i need help on. How do i parse xml to show up in a uilabel? And... Once that xml is parsed how can i scroll the text horizontally across the screen.

I have looked and found tutorials on parsing but they're for tables and I'm new to parsing so i don't know how to use that code and transfer it to a uilabel.

And on the automatic scrolling i would like for the text to move up and then scroll to completion. (like ESPN Scorecenter). Anyway thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSXMLParser for parsing your XML.